# How can I disable DNSSC for Google Apps (GMail) MX records on my authoritative domains?

Tags: dns, gmail, bind

I'm running a BIND Master / Slave setup with DNSSEC, but some of my domains use Google Apps for e-mail services.  Google doesn't support DNSSEC and BIND doesn't like it at all.

Log output:

```
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/AAAA/IN': 69.147.224.178#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755ca52c30: ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM A: bad cache hit (ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ALT2.ASPMX.L.GOOGLE.COM/A/IN': 69.147.224.178#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755ca52c30: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM A: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f754c1b0bd0: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM A: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/A/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f754c1a6a30: ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: error (broken trust chain) resolving 'ASPMX2.GOOGLEMAIL.COM/AAAA/IN': 70.32.45.42#53
Sep  6 17:12:51 srv549 named[5376]: validating @0x7f755cb83950: ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM AAAA: bad cache hit (ASPMX3.GOOGLEMAIL.COM.dlv.isc.org/DLV)
```

I'm not absolutely sure this is stopping Google Apps from working, because I just enabled all of the DNSSEC features.  Does anyone here have experience with this?

Comment: add this question into http://serverfault.com/

Comment: http://serverfault.com/questions/425252/how-can-i-disable-dnssc-for-google-apps-gmail-mx-records-on-my-authoritative-d

Thank you.